# IOS Swift and Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift

Let me apologize first, just learning swift, so I am not 100% on what I am doing. I have found many tutorials on integrating a facebook login in swift and have what appears to be working in the app, but it seems my delegates are never getting called. What I expect to happen is when a user logins 2 things should happen.

1) The login button for facebook should change to a logout button.
2) A console command should print that I logged in, and ultimately user information.

**ViewController Class is**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,FBLoginViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var fbLoginView : FBLoginView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.fbLoginView.delegate = self
        self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    }

    // Facebook Delegate Methods

    func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
        println("User Logged In")
        println("This is where you perform a segue.")
    }

    func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser){
        println("User Name: \(user.name)")
    }

    func loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
        println("User Logged Out")
    }

    func loginView(loginView : FBLoginView!, handleError:NSError) {
        println("Error: \(handleError.localizedDescription)")
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**AppDelegate sections** are:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FBLoginView.self
    FBProfilePictureView.self

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: NSString?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        var wasHandled:Bool = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)
        return wasHandled

    }

    return true
}
```

As you can see, most of this is straight from the tutorials but is not working correctly. I've got my info.plist configured, and the FBLoginView appears and goes thru the entire authentication, but nothing is printed to console and the button doesn't change.
 When I try to click it again, I get app already authorized, which should mean that the auth was successful, but nothing got triggered back in my app.

I feel confident that something is probably wrong with my appdelegate but being new to swift, I have no clue what..

Comment: Did you get anything in log ?

Comment: The only thing in the log is console output is "User Logged Out". Which I believe to be just because the fbLoginView is instantiated in a logged out manner.

Comment: When you click first time did it go for authentication ? and during that did it log any thing ?

Comment: It goes thru the entire facebook authentication. And nothing gets logged.. When you click it again it says you are already authorized

Comment: code looks ok, can you upload your code sith dummy facebook app ID i will replace it with mine and will update you about the result

Comment: my app ids have been removed from the info.plist.. didn't see anything else in the code that could be bad to share.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-xrZJv0zbslN3NYNFhVOTV4VUk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you the cheking of these steps:
-in your VC class, import FacebookSDK statement and FBLoginViewDelegate ?
 - your outlet should be:

```
//FB outlet
@IBOutlet var fbLoginView: FBLoginView
```

- in your AppDelegate.swift, also imported the FacebookSDK ?
 - you have a func in a func in your AppDelegate.swift.It should be:

```
import FacebookSDK
```

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //FB implementation
    FBLoginView.self
    FBProfilePictureView.self


    return true
}

//FB Method handles what happens after authentication
func application (application:UIApplication, openURL url:NSURL, sourceApplication:NSString?, annotation:AnyObject) -> Bool {
    //test var
    var wasHandled:Bool = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication)
// attempt to extract a token from the url
return wasHandled

}
```

Comment: For Clarity. The part that fixed it was I had my delegated functions inside the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" section instead of their own section.

Comment: You do not need: ``import FacebookSDK`` in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook as changed SDk. Please find the latest solution [here](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/)

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/