# How do I handle returning users with the login to facebook functionality?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I've been setting up an iOS app that will have login with Facebook capability. I'm using Swift, so I've been mostly following [this guide](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/) for Swift. In case the link goes stale: I believe it to be a howto and translation to Swift, of the on the 2.x version of [Facebook's "login with Facebook" buttton](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3).

I'm seeing some issues though. As long as I clear the simulator everything works fine. If I log out and then log back in again, everything works fine. The issue is when I log in and then rebuild the app, then the login button will remember that I logged in previously (it reads "Log out"), but the access token `FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()` is nil and any calls to the graph api fail. According to the documentation, this should just work. What am I doing wrong? What are the next steps to try to determine what the problem is?

I'm happy to post any code that may be relevant, however, very little of my code differs much from the boilerplate, and I'm not sure what may be relevant.

Is it possible this is happening because I'm only using the simulator?

Is it possible that I'm following the wrong examples? Most of the other [examples for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248182/ios-swift-and-facebook-sdk) that I've run across demonstrate using `FBLoginViewDelegate` instead of `FBLoginButtonDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to segue to your target view controller from viewDidAppear.
Here's a snippet of my viewDidAppear code you may find useful.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil{
        println("Not logged in")
    }else{
        println("Logged in")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Main Navigation Controller", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This code is in the view controller that the user logs in through.
If the user **is** already logged into facebook, the app will segue to the view controller I specified in `self.performSegueWithIdentifier`. In this case, my targeted view controller is called "*Main Navigation Controller*"

If the user **isn't** logged in, they will stay in the login view controller with the facebook login button displaying "*Log in*"

Comment: I have added that functionality, the issue is that, for returning users, the login button says "log out" but the `currentAccessToken() == nil`, so there is no way to segue until the user logs out and then logs in again.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from your Simulator and running it from scratch? There might be something in there that's messing around with the button's state.