# Have to hit "Done" button after signing into to Facebook on ios 9

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios9

I've spent way to long trying to fix this but after I sign in to my Facebook account and give permission for my app to use it the screen goes blanc except for a done button at the top left to hit. After I hit the done button, everything is normal but I tested this with other apps and I shouldn't have to do that. What am I doing wrong. I have the newest Facebook sdk 4.6 I believe, I think my .plist is right, and I have all frameworks added.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb497638107079749</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>NUMBER</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>What's Up</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

[screen with done button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip4OS.png)

[Previous screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTzmq.png)

The function login Button doesn't run until I hit the done button

```
 import UIKit
 import FBSDKLoginKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
   //@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil){
        print("user is not logged in")

    }else{
        print("user is logged in")
    }

    loginButton.delegate = self
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]
    print("this is all good")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    print("clicked")

    if (error == nil){
        print("Login Complete")


            print("i am in the if")



        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNew", sender: self)
    }else{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}


func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    print("user logged out")
}
```

Comment: once reset simulator and try again.

Comment: I added the code but I check it with a tutorial and it was exactly what another person had for ios 8 but I can't find a tutorial for ios 9 and I struggle with objective-c so the documentation doesn't help much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248182/ios-swift-and-facebook-sdk check with this link.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, you have 2 NSTransportSecurity Keys in your pList. Please configure them as one as following like this.

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This is the part of the `plist` with only the key value of `NSAppTransportSecurity`. Please try this once and confirm what is happening.

Also follow the code in your `AppDelegate.m`. Please configure your AppDelegate.m as following

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>



@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

  //This is very important for callback

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {


          return  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
        }

    }

@end
```

Please try all these and comment what is happening , so that we can help you out.

Comment: So I fixed it. I made a mistake in the AppDelegate but I'm not quite sure what is was cause a just copy and pasted a previous project of mine. I will figure it out in a minute and post what I changed.